# The .on() delegated event is not firing

Tags: jquery

I've had a similar issue to this in the past because I wasn't using delegated events.
Now I am using a delegated event, but it still doesn't work for the newly changed id.
What would be the reason that this delegated event doesn't work for dom changes, and how would I remedy this?

Here is an example of two divs swapping the id 'show'.  Whenever a 'show' list item is clicked, it is supposed to fire the using the delegated event .on, but it does not.

```
    <style>.hide {display:none;}</style>
    <div id="show">
        <span id="number" class="hide">2</span>
        <span id="list" class="hide">item1,item3</span>
        <ul class="img_list">
            <li>Something</li>
            <li>Something</li>
            <li>Something</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="box">
            <button type="button" class="hide" id="checkanswer">check answer</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide">
        <span id="number" class="hide">1</span>
        <span id="list" class="hide">item1</span>
        <ul class="img_list">
            <li>Something</li>
            <li>Something</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="box">
            <button type="button" class="hide" id="checkanswer">check answer</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    var selection_required=$('#show #number').html();

    $('#show').on('click', '.img_list li', function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass("selected");}
        if ($('.selected').length==selection_required){ 
             $("#show #checkanswer").fadeIn( "slow", function() {});
            }
        else{
            $("#show #checkanswer").fadeOut( "slow", function() {});
        }
    });

    $('#checkanswer').click(function(){
        parent=$(this).parent().parent();
        next=$(this).parent().parent().next();
        parent.removeAttr("id");
        parent.addClass("hide");
        next.attr("id","show");
        next.removeClass("hide");
        selection_required=next.find('#number').html();
        item_array=next.find("#list").html();
        next.show();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: `var selection_required=$('#show #number').html();` and comparing that to `$('.selected').length==selection_required` seems like it will never work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by other commenters you need this for your `.on` event:

```
$(document).on('click', '#show .img_list li', function () {...
```

But you also need to **reset** your `.selected` class in that `.on` event like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '#show .img_list li', function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
                $(this).removeClass("selected");
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass("selected");
            }
            if ($('.selected').length == selection_required) {
                $("#show #checkanswer").fadeIn("slow", function () { });
                $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            }
            else {
                $("#show #checkanswer").fadeOut("slow", function () { });
            }
        });
```

The `$('.selected').removeClass('selected');` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Delegation works by binding an event listener to one element that receives events that bubble up from its children. The reason it’s used when elements change dynamically is because the event is still attached to an element; if you make the delegate an element that changes, it defeats the purpose. Instead, you  can go one level up, wherever that is – or even just to `document`.

```
$(document).on('click', '#show .img_list li', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass("selected");}
    if ($('.selected').length==selection_required){ 
         $("#show #checkanswer").fadeIn( "slow", function() {});
        }
    else{
        $("#show #checkanswer").fadeOut( "slow", function() {});
    }
});
```

Your first `if` can be `$(this).toggleClass("selected")`, by the way.

Comment: The "$(document).on('click', '#show .img_list li'" was the first thing I tried and this failed.

It does trigger it though; the checkanswer button doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

try to do the delegation like this on document

```
 $(document).on('click','#show .img_list li',function(){
...
});
```